# Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed when trying to apply conditional format to multiple columns of table

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I've a strange thingy going on. I've created a Sub to apply conditional formating rules to a Table, tbl_caskinfo.

When I run the Sub from the VBA editor it all works fine BUT when I launch the Sub from a button in a custom Ribbon it fails with the message:

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

That's all in Excel 2016 at home.

At work with Excel 2019/365 it fails like it does via the button in Excel 2016. So I must be doing something wrong but I don't understand it :(

The line it breaks on is:

> Set rng = Range("tbl_caskinfo[Act. Yield];tbl_caskinfo[Act. Bottles];tbl_caskinfo[Act. Final Payment];tbl_caskinfo[Act. Bottle Price];tbl_caskinfo[[Bottled]:[Bottled ABV]]")

When I leave only 1 column in the line, or a set of adjecent columns, then it works fine (regards the version or location the Sub is triggered from).

So what am I missing here?

Comment: I'd suspect the problem is the semicolons in the address. Try using commas, or use Union with the actual Listobject's Listcolumns.

Comment: Big massive facepalm on my side :| Thanks @Rory, that solved the issue! Strange though that it did actually work under Excel 2016 when triggered from the VBA editor.